# cocoa ffmpeg streaming created improper file

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, ffmpeg, rtmp

I am trying to capture video stream and upload it to RTMP server using FFMPEG in my cocoa app. I am able to play that file via FFPLAY but when i stop streaming **file is not created properly**.

It shows file size as **1kb** even when streaming is done for **5 mins**.

However if i try to save on my local system it works fine. A proper file is created and i am able to view it.

RTMP server is also fine coz from windows files are being created and saved on that server.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating FFMPEG to version 3.1.4 solved my problem of streaming via terminal.